# App firstrun principal form is form1 after firstrun principal form is Inicio

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need help , I have a game in vb.net I want to FirstRun program open a form that gives by the nick and has a mini tutorial etc. , and after FirstRun the form startup switches to the game without appears to form by the nickname.

I Tried:

```
Private Sub Inicio_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.FirstRun = True Then
        My.Settings.FirstRun = False
        My.Settings.Save()
    ElseIf My.Settings.FirstRun = False Then
        Dim Inicio As Inicio
            Inicio = New Inicio
        Inicio.Hide()
        Dim Form1 As Form1
        Form1 = New Form1
        Form1.Show()
    End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

But principal form (Inicio) appears with form1.
Im new in programming, can someone help me?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what do you want.. DO you want Inicio to hide after form1.show?

Comment: `Me.Hide()`. By calling `Dim Inicio As Inicio : Inicio = New Inicio` you create a new form that you never use. Refer to the current form by using `Me`.